# Powershell Get -ChildItem: filtering csv files and -Recurse not working

Tags: powershell

I created a short powershell script to convert csv files from Unicode to UTF-8 encoding. My script outputs new files with the the original file name preceded by UTF8. I'm running into two issues:

1. I'm trying to only run the powershell script on csv files. Currently the script runs on every file in the directory, including the powershell script (it outputs a new file called UTF8pshell_script if the powershell script was called pshell_script for example). The other methods where I've tried to only run the script on csv files just end up making the script not do anything.
2. I'm trying to run the script on sub-directories. The first issue is that output files created from csv files in subdirectories have no content inside them whatsoever. If the script is ran in the same directory as the csv file this problem does not arise. This is not crucial but I am also uncertain how to get output files created from those in subdirectories to be outputted in the same subdirectories (currently they are outputted in the main directory where the powershell script is).
   as

```
    Get-Content -Encoding Unicode $_ | Out-File -Encoding UTF8
    Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ForEach-Object {Get-Content -Encoding Unicode $_ | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 "UTF8$_"}
```

The desired output is the powershell script running on only csv files, and outputting files to the same subdirectories where the files they were created form are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the original encoding (and presence of a BOM) you might have to specify an encoding also on the input side.

```
ForEach($Csv in (Get-ChildItem -Filter *.csv -Recurse -Exclude UTF8*)){
  (Get-Content $Csv.FullName -raw) | 
    Set-Content -Path {Join-Path $Csv.Directory ("UTF8"+$Csv.Name)} -Encoding UTF8
}
```

Comment: This correctly outputs the csv files to their correct subdirectories, but doesn't show the most of the content from the original csv file (It only shows the value of one row from the original csv file)

Comment: As the script doesn't change the content aside from saving with a different `-Encoding` I'm a bit curious, what `-Encoding` do the original files ***have***?

Comment: I append that to the script.

Comment: The same thing is still happening. If you would like to test the script locally, here are two sample csv files that I am using:


csv1: https://anonymousfiles.io/MfUViaJp/


csv2: https://anonymousfiles.io/tPezSszV/


powershell script: https://anonymousfiles.io/wbR6CPzA/

Comment: Changed script to use the `-raw` parameter with `Get-Content` and now have the very same output.

Answer (score 2):

`Get-ChildItem` takes a `-Filter` parameter, which for files is the simple wildcard pattern. This will allow you to restrict your cmdlet to CSV files only:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.csv
```

To process subdirectories, you may also use the `-Recurse` switch

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.csv -Recurse
```

Now, I'm never quite sure how `$_` changes as you pass different objects through the pipe, so I'm probably not doing the next steps the most efficient way - but it will be clear what I'm trying to do:

Each file object that we find needs to be processed as follows:

1. Dissect it into a path and a filename: `$filepath = $_.PSParentPath; $filename = $_.PSChildName`
2. Load up the CSV: `Import-CSV -Path $_`
3. Output the new CSV with the proper encoding: `Export-CSV -Path ("{0}\UTF8{1}" -f $filepath,$filename) -Encoding UTF8`

So, we put it all together:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.csv -Recurse -exclude UTF8* | ForEach-Object { 
    $filepath = $_.PSParentPath
    $filename = $_.PSChildName
    Import-CSV -Path $_ | 
       Export-CSV -Encoding UTF8 -Path ("{0}\UTF8{1}" -f $filepath,$filename) -NoTypeInformation
}
```

The `-Exclude UTF8*` in the `Get-ChildItem` ensures that when you create a file, it doesn't get picked up later and re-processed. The `-NoTypeInformation` on the `Export-CSV` compensates for a stupidity built in to the cmdlet that causes an extra line with a meaningless object type name at the beginning of the file.

Comment: When using `Import-Csv` I'd also use `Export-Csv`, but if there is no header (and the first data line hasn't unique fields), your approach might fail.

Comment: @LotPings - good point, and I should have included `-NoTypeInformation` on the `Export-CSV` even if you assume that the imported CSV is perfect.

Comment: Honestly, if he is just doing encoding conversion he doesn't care about the contents, so `Import-Csv` converting everything to objects, then `Export-Csv` converting everything back to text is just a whole lot of extra cycles.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, the only issue (but non consequential) is that in each directory two files are created for each existing csv as opposed to one. The first is titled UTF8 + filename, and the second is UTF8UTF8 + filename (they are identical)

Comment: @starch If you don't exclude file names beginning with `UTF8` on successive runs you'll get a growing list of files with `UTF8UTF8...`

Comment: @LotPings - Good catch on the `-Exclude`! I suspect that I assumed that the `Get-ChildItem` would be done executing by the time the `Export-CSV` was running...

Answer (score 1):

LotPings beat me to this by 10 minutes with a virtually identical answer, but I'm leaving this for the 'passing an empty file to the pipeline' bit that I have. I also realize after the fact that you don't need a pipeline variable for that same reason, as you only need it if you pass things through the pipeline within the loop.

If all you want to do is change the encoding I would use a `ForEach($x in $y){}` loop, or a `ForEach-Object{}` loop with a `PipelineVariable` on the `Get-ChildItem`. I'll show that since I think pipeline variables are under used. I would also not read the file and pipe it to something, since if the file is empty you won't create a new file as nothing is passed down the pipeline.

```
Get-ChildItem *.csv -Recurse -PipelineVariable File | ForEach-Object{
    Set-Content -Value (Get-Content $File.FullName -Encoding Unicode) -Path {Join-Path $File.Directory "UTF8$($File.Name)"} -Encoding UTF8
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to output anything

Answer (score 0):

if you specify the file extension at the end of `Get-ChildItem`.
This will get only the files with the .csv extension.

By specifying the File path in Out-File it will send it to the specified directory.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\folder\*.csv -Recurse | ForEach-Object {Get-Content -Encoding Unicode $_ | Out-File -FilePath C:\Folder -Encoding UTF8 "UTF8$_"}
```

Comment: @LotPings What do you mean flatten the subdirs?

Comment: Point 2 of OPs requirements. You are recursing with gci and applying a fixed folder for output.

Comment: That is why @Jeff Zeitlin uses $_.PSParentpath. His is closest to the OPs question

Comment: This also does not seem to output anything